# Subquery in ORDER BY SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, subquery

I'm trying to convert a SQL query into SQLAlchemy Query Language.
In order to understand a little the sense of the query, I have a table *security* and a table *valuation*.
The *security* table describes the different securities (stocks) I'm following on the market :

```
 id   |           bbg_ticker
------+-------------------------
    1 | 3993 HK Equity
    2 | A2A IM Equity
    3 | AA UN Equity
    4 | AA/ LN Equity
    5 | AAL LN Equity
    6 | AALB NA Equity
    7 | ABBN VX Equity
```

The *valuation* table describes the values for **one security** and for **one day** :

```
security_id |    date    |  px_close   |   volume
------------+------------+-------------+-------------
          1 | 2015-05-18 |       6.754 |     9890000
          1 | 2015-05-19 |       6.802 |    11660773
          1 | 2015-05-20 |       6.802 |    12674694
          1 | 2015-05-21 |       6.735 |     5533000
          1 | 2015-05-22 |        6.85 |    10096288
          2 | 2015-05-18 |      1.0558 |    32198683
          2 | 2015-05-19 |      1.0577 |    17630748
          2 | 2015-05-20 |      1.0606 |    11990913
          2 | 2015-05-21 |      1.0722 |    24492170
          2 | 2015-05-22 |      1.0887 |    28795865
          3 | 2015-05-18 |     13.3587 |     3107029
          3 | 2015-05-19 |     13.0397 |     6276252
          3 | 2015-05-20 |     13.0297 |     3746343
          3 | 2015-05-21 |     12.9599 |     4023997
          3 | 2015-05-22 |     12.9001 |     3438908
          4 | 2015-05-18 |     403.949 |     2059825
          4 | 2015-05-19 |     404.937 |     1153599
          4 | 2015-05-20 |     405.035 |      769304
          4 | 2015-05-21 |     403.455 |      586507
          4 | 2015-05-22 |     399.998 |      878268
          5 | 2015-05-18 |    1049.328 |     4957938
```

What I'm trying to do is taking the 10th best securities, classified by *volume*, at **one precise date**. The problem is that sometimes there is no data for this specific date (for instance the week-end), so I want to take the last volume value (the nearest in the past).

I have found the solution in pure SQL (here is an example for 23th of May 2015 as date):

```
SELECT s.bbg_ticker
FROM security s
INNER JOIN valuation v1
    ON v1.security_id = s.id
    AND v1.volume IS NOT NULL
    AND v1.px_close iS NOT NULL
    AND v1.date > '2015-05-16'     # because I don't want too old values..
    AND v1.date <= '2015-05-23'
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY (SELECT v.volume
    FROM valuation v
    WHERE v.security_id = s.id
        AND v.volume IS NOT NULL
        AND v.px_close IS NOT NULL
        AND v.date > '2015-05-16'  # same
        AND v.date <= '2015-05-23'
    ORDER BY v.date DESC LIMIT 1
) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I want to do the same thing, but with SQLAlchemy Query Language. As there are a lot of repetition in my SQL query, I'm pretty sure I can do something smarter with SQLAlchemy without repetition.

I don't manage to do the subquery inside the "ORDER BY" with SQLAlchemy.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you,
Ed

EDIT :

My first idea is to do something like :

```
 Security.query.join(Valuation)\
      .filter(
          Valuation.volume != None,
          Valuation.px_close != None,
          Valuation.date <= date(2015, 05, 23),
          Valuation.date > date(2015, 05, 16)
      ).order_by(
          db.session.query(Valuation.volume).filter(
              Valuation.volume != None,
              Valuation.px_close != None,
              Valuation.date <= date(2015, 05, 23),
              Valuation.date > date(2015, 05, 16)
          ).desc()
      )
```

but :

- I have an error concerning the desc() : "AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'desc'"
- I have not the link "WHERE v.security_id = s.id" in the subquery, because I have no access to the "security" in the subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the solution:

```
Security.query.join(Valuation)\
        .filter(tuple_(Valuation.security_id, Valuation.date).in_(
            db.session.query(Valuation.stock_id, func.max(Valuation.date))\
            .filter(Valuation.volume != None,
                    Valuation.px_close != None,
                    Valuation.date > date(2015, 05, 16),
                    Valuation.date <= date(2015, 05, 23))
            .group_by(Valuation.security_id)))
            .order_by(Valuation.volume.desc())
            .limit(10)
            .all()
```

which produces:

```
SELECT security.*
FROM security
    JOIN valuation ON security.id = valuation.security_id
    WHERE (valuation.security_id, valuation.date) IN (
        SELECT valuation.security_id, max(valuation.date)
        FROM valuation
        WHERE valuation.volume IS NOT NULL
            AND valuation.px_close IS NOT NULL
            AND valuation.date > "2015-05-16"
            AND valuation.date <= "2015-05-23"
            GROUP BY valuation.security_id
    )
ORDER BY valuation.volume DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Which is more efficient and doesn't need repetition.